# Pandas Dataframe Lookup using partial column name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I'm trying to lookup a value from selected column's using a value from my Dataframe. My lookup value needs to identify which column name it matches out of the selected columns, for example below I only want to consider columns ending in JT in my vlookup.

Example of dataframe:

| Plan1_JT | Plan2_JT | Plan3_JT | Plan1_T | Plan2_T | JT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 89 | 67 | 25 | 67 | 90 | Plan1 |
| 9 | 45 | 7 | 6 | 5 | Plan3 |
| 45 | 3 | 2 | 6 | 23 | Plan1 |

Outcome:

| Plan1_JT | Plan2_JT | Plan3_JT | Plan1_T | Plan2_T | JT | Plan_JT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 89 | 67 | 25 | 67 | 90 | Plan1 | 89 |
| 9 | 45 | 7 | 6 | 5 | Plan3 | 7 |
| 45 | 3 | 2 | 6 | 23 | Plan1 | 45 |

Example code:

```
df2['Plan_JT'].astype(str)=df2.loc[:,('Plan1_JT','Plan2_JT','Plan3_JT')].str.contains.iloc[1:5]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for old pandas versions with [`DataFrame.lookup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html):

```
df['new'] = df.lookup(df.index, df['JT'] + '_JT')
print (df)
   Plan1_JT  Plan2_JT  Plan3_JT  Plan1_T  Plan2_T     JT  new
0        89        67        25       67       90  Plan1   89
1         9        45         7        6        5  Plan3    7
2        45         3         2        6       23  Plan1   45
```

And for last versions with [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html):

```
melt = df.melt('JT', ignore_index=False)

df['new'] = melt.loc[melt['JT'] + '_JT' == melt['variable'], 'value']
print (df)
   Plan1_JT  Plan2_JT  Plan3_JT  Plan1_T  Plan2_T     JT  new
0        89        67        25       67       90  Plan1   89
1         9        45         7        6        5  Plan3    7
2        45         3         2        6       23  Plan1   45
```

Comment: Great thank you! It works, but getting this error :

A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: @Lilly - How is created `df2` in your code?

Comment: I created it when removing any nan's : df2=df1[~df1.JT.str.contains("nan")]

Comment: @Lilly - then use `df2=df1[~df1.JT.str.contains("nan")].copy()`